# Flex: Problems using scale9Grid with Image

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to create an image component that can be scaled using 9-slice scaling.

I'm 100% positive the grid rectangle is inside the image's bounds. However, the scale9Grid property seems not to affect anything.

I have tried many different things. Here is my last attempt where I try to put the image in a canvas. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="init()"
    >

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.BitmapAsset;
        import mx.controls.Image;

        [Embed(source="assets/image.png")]
        private var barImageClass:Class;
        private var barImage:Image;

        private function init():void
        {
            barImage = new Image();
            barImage.addChild( new Bitmap( (new barImageClass() as BitmapAsset).bitmapData ) );

            barImage.scale9Grid = new Rectangle( 120, 4, 2, 2 );

            barImage.scaleX = 2;

            addChild( barImage );
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to apply the scale9Grid to the bitmap, instead of to the sprite/movieclip it's inside of.

Answer (score -1):

See [this adobe doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=embed_082_9.html). I think it will solve your problem. Cheers